# Inserting data into cloudsql using cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am just trying to insert one data into Cloud Sql using Cloud Functions.I have written a simple code within cloud functions.

I have just deployed it using deploy button it is showing success.Within insertcloudsql insert statement is written.Now from where should I call this function so that I am able to see the inserted rows into cloudsql.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to trigger a cloud function, depending on your use case and architecture. Maybe this helps? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling

Comment: Basically I want when the file will be placed in google cloud storage then cloud functions (within which one insert statemnet is there)will insert the data into cloud sql

Comment: I have found this link to a tutorial that can do this. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage

Comment: You are asking how to trigger the function and there are eight or so different ways how you can trigger a cloud function. The link I posted lists them, but only you can decide which one makes sense for in your case

Comment: What is your global picture?

Comment: Picture is like that I want to take file from cloud storage and want to transform and load into cloudsql.how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you use the [cloud storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-python), the data will be written anytime you make a change on your bucket, that change can be set by using the right object type for your use case. eg Trigger type value: google.storage.object.finalize, will trigger your function whenever you upload or overwrite a cloud storage object. If the files are there already, then you should chose another way to trigger your function.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of having the function is so that you can manually trigger it to insert some data to your Cloud SQL instance, there's no point in creating CLoud Function in the first place.

You can connect to your CLoud SQL instance using an SQL client of choice and do it there. You can also install Cloud SQL Proxy locally and then connect to your CLoud SQL instance as if it's running locally.

The point of spinning Cloud Functions is to have some business logic that is triggered based on your business requirements. Maybe it's an HTTP call, maybe it's a PubSub message, etc. Those functions can naturally store things in databases, including Cloud SQL, but it's not clear based on your question if you are using the right tool for the job.

Comment: a cloud function can server as an https endpoint - a webhook for example - and then the function writes to the database.  a webhook expects a url endpoint not a database connection